# How do I wait on a timer before returning location?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps, nstimer

I am trying to write a method to return the current location. While I'm waiting a period of 30sec, 1 min, or 2 minutes (set in settings) I display an alert view. I allow the user to bypass the timer wait with an alertView button accepting the current accuracy which I will display and update in the alert view. My code has a couple of holes in it I need help with. Essentially, it is to know how to have the getCurrentLocation method wait on the timer. I can't just use a delay because I  plan to force the timer to expire if the user hits the button or if the location accuracy is met (this is checked in timer). Here is the code:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod {
    static int elapsedTime = 0;
    elapsedTime++;
    if (elapsedTime >= gpsTimeout) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        elapsedTime = 0; // reset static variable
        // !!! How do I do the following !!!
        //  do something to allow getCurrentLocation to return
    }
    if ((currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= gpsDesiredAccuracy) & (currentLocation.verticalAccuracy <= 2*gpsDesiredAccuracy)) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        elapsedTime = 0; // reset static variable
        //  do something to allow getCurrentLocation to return
    }
}

- (CLLocation *)getCurrentLocation {
    // check if current accuracy is good enough and return if true
    if ((currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= gpsDesiredAccuracy) & (currentLocation.verticalAccuracy <= 2*gpsDesiredAccuracy)) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        return currentLocation;
    } else {
        // show alert with count down timer
        UIAlertView *gpsAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"tbd put in timer and list location accuracy updates" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue With Current Accuracy" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [gpsAlertView show];
        // start timer
        NSTimer *gpsTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                         target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:)
                                                       userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        // !!! How do I do the following !!!
        // wait for when timer expires,
        // the user to press "Continue With Current Accuracy" button (can force timer to expire?)   
        return currentLocation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to wait on any timer or for any accelerometer or user event is to simply exit the current method back to the UI run loop by using a return statement.

Anything you want done after the wait can go in the timer or event callback method.

Comment: That seems to make sense. I was stuck on shoehorning the gps feature into my App by doing things the same way as without gps. I'll work on this over the next day or two and report back on how it goes.

Comment: Up and running now. Your suggestion worked out. I also found a good reference in Apple's LocateMe sample code.